# Sending the address content with mpi_send

Tags: c, mpi

I'm writing a program which sends to every process an array of 2 numbers.
I did't ok with array notation. The problem is that if I want to use pointer notation with an address memory allocated with malloc, I can't access to the second element. 
In this example the program sends an array with pointer notation which contains the numbers 1 and 2 to every process. Then the root prints the received message. Thanks

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    float *send = malloc(sizeof(float) * 2);
    float *recv = malloc(sizeof(float) * 2);

/*
    float send2[2], recv2[2];
    send2[0] = 1;
    send2[1] = 2;
*/

    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    *(send) = 1;
    *(send + sizeof(float)) = 2;
    MPI_Send(send, 2, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            MPI_Recv(recv, 2, MPI_FLOAT, i, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            printf("[%f][%f]\n", *(recv), *(recv + sizeof(float)));
            //printf("[%f][%f]\n", recv2[0], recv2[1]);
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the result

```
juan@um18:~/Documentos/EjemplosMPI$ mpirun -np 4 ejecutables/ex
[1.000000][0.000000]
[1.000000][0.000000]
[1.000000][0.000000]
[1.000000][0.000000]
```

Comment: For any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. Now think about `*(send + sizeof(float)) = 2` a little more, and why using array-indexing syntax is recommended (besides being less to write).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, after spend almost 3 hours I realized that

```
*(send + sizeof(float))=2
```

Must be

```
*(send + 1) = 2;
```

And the same thing to the recv function. 
I thought that moving along the array you have to increase de address memory calculating the size, but this is only if you are using a void pointer. If you declare as a float pointer, the program knows how big is that size.